# Write x509 certificate into PEM formatted string in java?

Tags: java, x509, pem, der

Is there some high level way to write an X509Certificate into a PEM formatted string?
Currently I'm doing x509cert.encode() to write it into a DER formatted string, then base 64 encoding it and appending the header and footer to create a PEM string, but it seems bad. Especially since I have to throw in line breaks too.

Comment: Also a similar function in _okhttp-tls_, written in Kotlin : https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-4.10.0/okhttp-tls/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/tls/Certificates.kt#L67

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This is not bad. Java doesn't provide any functions to write PEM files. What you are doing is the correct way. Even KeyTool does the same thing,

```java
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
out.println(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT);
encoder.encodeBuffer(cert.getEncoded(), out);
out.println(X509Factory.END_CERT);
```

If you use BouncyCastle, you can use PEMWriter class to write out X509 certificate in PEM.

Comment: PEMWriter is now deprecated. JcaPEMWriter is the newer class that replaces it.

Comment: Can you include the declaration for `out`?

Comment: See [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816183/1121497) about using BouncyCastle `PemWriter`.

Answer (score 39):

Haven't seen anyone bring up Java 8's `Base64.getMimeEncoder` method yet - actually allows you to specify both the line length *and* line separator like so:

```
final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getMimeEncoder(64, LINE_SEPARATOR.getBytes());
```

I looked to see if there was any difference with this ^ vs the standard encoder, and I couldn't find anything.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#basic) cites [RFC 2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) for both BASIC and MIME encoders, with the addition of [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) for BASIC.  AFAIK both of these standards use the same Base64 alphabet (tables look the same), so you should fine to use MIME if you need to specify a line length.

This means that with Java 8, this can be accomplished with:

```
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;
```

...

```
public static final String BEGIN_CERT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
public static final String END_CERT = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
public final static String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

...

```
public static String formatCrtFileContents(final Certificate certificate) throws CertificateEncodingException {
    final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getMimeEncoder(64, LINE_SEPARATOR.getBytes());

    final byte[] rawCrtText = certificate.getEncoded();
    final String encodedCertText = new String(encoder.encode(rawCrtText));
    final String prettified_cert = BEGIN_CERT + LINE_SEPARATOR + encodedCertText + LINE_SEPARATOR + END_CERT;
    return prettified_cert;
}
```

Comment: Call requires API level 26.

Answer (score 23):

Previous answer gives compatibility problems with 3de party software (like PHP), because PEM cert is not correctly chunked.

Imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Code:

```
protected static String convertToPem(X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateEncodingException {
 Base64 encoder = new Base64(64);
 String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
 String end_cert = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

 byte[] derCert = cert.getEncoded();
 String pemCertPre = new String(encoder.encode(derCert));
 String pemCert = cert_begin + pemCertPre + end_cert;
 return pemCert;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be in lines of 64 characters for OpenSSL generally.

Answer (score 15):

The following uses no big external libraries or possibly version-inconsistent sun.* libraries. It builds on judoman's answer, but it also chunks lines at 64 characters, as required by OpenSSL, Java, and others.

Import:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.StringWriter;
```

Code:

```
public static String certToString(X509Certificate cert) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        sw.write("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n");
        sw.write(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cert.getEncoded()).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n"));
        sw.write("\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");
    } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

(I would have just commented on judoman's answer, but I don't have enough reputation points to be allowed to comment, and my simple edit was rejected because it should have been a comment or an answer, so here's the answer.)

If you want to write straight to file, also `import java.io.FileWriter` and:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(certFilePath);
fw.write(certToString(myCert));
fw.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately javax.xml.bind has been removed in Java 11. The best option now seems to be to use`Base64.encodeBase64String` from `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` instead of `printBase64Binary`.

Answer (score 12):

If you have PEMWriter from bouncy castle, then you can do the following :

Imports :

```
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;
```

Code :

```
/**
 * Converts a {@link X509Certificate} instance into a Base-64 encoded string (PEM format).
 *
 * @param x509Cert A X509 Certificate instance
 * @return PEM formatted String
 * @throws CertificateEncodingException
 */
public String convertToBase64PEMString(Certificate x509Cert) throws IOException {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try (PEMWriter pw = new PEMWriter(sw)) {
        pw.writeObject(x509Cert);
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: It will return empty string now, to fix this add this after writing object "pw.flush()".

Comment: I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816183/1121497) with `PemWriter`, since `PEMWriter` is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

To build on ZZ Coder's idea, but without using the `sun.misc` classes that aren't guaranteed to be consistent between JRE versions, consider this

Use Class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
```

Code:

```
try {
    System.out.println("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(x509cert.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");
} catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: None of the sun.* classes are intended to be stable: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: Thanks pimlottc.  I removed the sun.security.provider.X509Factory field references and replaced them with string values.

Answer (score 6):

In BouncyCastle 1.60 `PEMWriter` has been deprecated in favour of `PemWriter`.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

try (PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw)) {
  PemObjectGenerator gen = new JcaMiscPEMGenerator(cert);
  pw.writeObject(gen);
}

return sw.toString();
```

`PemWriter` is buffered so you do need to flush/close it before accessing the writer that it was constructed with.

Comment: This is THE answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Almost the same as @[Andy Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763035/andy-brown) one less line of code.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

try (JcaPEMWriter jpw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw)) {
    jpw.writeObject(cert);
}

String pem = sw.toString();
```

As he said PEMWriter is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another alternative for encoding using [Guava's BaseEncoding](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html):

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;

public static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
public static final int LINE_LENGTH = 64;
```

And then:

```
String encodedCertText = BaseEncoding.base64()
                                     .withSeparator(LINE_SEPARATOR, LINE_LENGTH)
                                     .encode(cert.getEncoded());
```

Comment: Need to add the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` lines too.

Comment: Thank you! you saved my life after 24hours of search

Answer (score 2):

Using some tiny Base64 I made below thing which does not depend on other things like base64 or bouncycastle.

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
class Convert {
    private static byte[] convertToPem(X509Certificate cert)
        throws CertificateEncodingException {
        String cert_begin = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        String end_cert = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        String b64 = encode(cert.getEncoded()).replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n");
        if (b64.charAt(b64.length() - 1) != '\n') end_cert = "\n" + end_cert;
        String outpem = cert_begin + b64 + end_cert;
        return outpem.getBytes();
    }

    // Taken from https://gist.github.com/EmilHernvall/953733
    private static String encode(byte[] data) {
        String tbl = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        int pad = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
            int b = ((data[i] & 0xFF) << 16) & 0xFFFFFF;
            if (i + 1 < data.length) b |= (data[i+1] & 0xFF) << 8;
            else pad++;
            if (i + 2 < data.length) b |= (data[i+2] & 0xFF);
            else pad++;
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 - pad; j++, b <<= 6) {
                int c = (b & 0xFC0000) >> 18;
                buffer.append(tbl.charAt(c));
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < pad; j++) buffer.append("=");
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `replaceAll("(.{64})", "$1\n");` +1!

Comment: @RobAu I have taken that line from [this](https://github.com/SaitoLab-Nitech/ApkSign)

Answer (score 2):

Java 11 update:

```
System.out.println(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT);
System.out.println(java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder(64, 
    new byte[] {'\r', '\n'}).encodeToString(cert.getEncoded()));
System.out.println(X509Factory.END_CERT);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `BouncyCastle` this is one way to do it:

```java
// You may need to add BouncyCastle as provider:
public static init() {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}

public static String encodePEM(Certificate certificate) {
    return encodePEM("CERTIFICATE", certificate.encoded);
}
public static String encodePEM(PrivateKey privateKey) {
    return encodePEM("PRIVATE KEY", privateKey.encoded);
}
public static String encodePEM(PublicKey publicKey) {
    return encodePEM("PUBLIC KEY", publicKey.encoded);
}    
/**
 * Converts byte array to PEM
 */
protected static String toPEM(String type, byte[] data) {
  final PemObject pemObject = new PemObject(type, data);
  final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  try (final PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw)) {
    pw.writeObject(pemObject);
  }
  return sw.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [okhttp3-tls](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-tls) it is possible in one line

```java
import okhttp3.tls.certificatePem

String certPem = cert.certificatePem()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).