# how to save a self signed certeficate as a pem file in Java

Tags: java, file, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I have implemented a function in Java that generates a self signed certeficate.
the output is of type X509Certificate.
How can I print my certeficate or how to save it as a readable file ..

Comment: would be great to know why this question was downvoted...it was a pretty clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using BouncyCastle API.  Here is the link for PEMWriter class javadocs : https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMWriter.html

Also, found a stackoverflow question dealing with a similar issue: [Write x509 certificate into PEM formatted string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313020/write-x509-certificate-into-pem-formatted-string-in-java)