# Using AWS Iot SDK v2 with certificates from java keystore

Tags: keystore, pem, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-iot-core

I'm adding AWS connectivity to an existing Java application using the AWS IoT SDK for Java v2 (common-runtime-based), and I want to use a certificate and private key in my existing keystore to establish the connection to MQTT.

There's an API and fairly straightforward instructions for doing this for the old v1 (Paho-based) library: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java#load-keystore-from-file-to-initialize-the-client, but I'd like to follow recommendations and use the newer/better-supported v2 library if possible. It looks like the v2 library does not have a straightforward API for interacting with Java keystores -- the closest thing is the newMtlsBuilder function which takes PEM-format strings.

Is the best answer here that I have to load the certificates using the Java keystore APIs and then translate them to PEM myself, with something like this [Write x509 certificate into PEM formatted string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313020/write-x509-certificate-into-pem-formatted-string-in-java)? Or else use the v1 SDK even though it's deprecated? Or am I missing something in the v2 SDK?

More broadly, could anyone recommend a good Java-oriented write-up of CRT concepts and usage anywhere? Or maybe a guide for how to migrate from v1 to v2 of the SDK? The github docs for the C libraries are somewhat useful (e.g. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-c-io) but I'm not very familiar with C and it's a little tricky to figure out how the C concepts/methods/structs will map to the Java bindings.

Comment: Did you manage anywhere to find a solution for this?

Comment: Yeah, my research did not turn up any Java-oriented write-up of CRT concepts unfortunately. I did end up getting something working, which I shared on this github issue on the project: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2/issues/180, but for the project we ended up pivoting to use the v1 library instead for it's more robust Java feature set

Comment: I will check that topic on GH. Thanks :)